# .next folder is missing some files using Docker on CentOS in production mode

Tags: reactjs, docker, centos, next.js

I am running a `next.js` project and everything is OK when I try building in `production` mode on my local system.

Even when I use docker on my system whose OS is `ubuntu 18.04.2` building and running the project is successfully done. But when code is run on the server whose OS is `CentOS 7.6.1810`, some files in `.next` folder is missed which leads to error in running the project :(

This is my setup in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "with-redux-wrapper",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node server",
    "export": "next export"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.4.3",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-source-maps": "0.0.4-canary.1",
    "animated-scroll-to": "^1.2.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "next": "8.1.0",
    "next-cookies": "^1.1.3",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "2.0.0",
    "next-routes": "^1.0.17",
    "next-seo": "^1.12.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-datepicker2": "^2.0.5",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-hotjar": "^2.0.0",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-markdown": "^4.0.8",
    "react-persian-datepicker": "^3.0.2",
    "react-recaptcha": "^2.3.8",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-scroll-up": "^1.3.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.21.0",
    "react-slick-16": "^0.16.1",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-api-middleware": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "persian-date": "^1.1.0",
    "serve": "^11.1.0"
  }
}
```

And my `Dockerfile` which forced me to comment the commented lines because `production` mode causes problems:

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine AS build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm install --verbose
# --> ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY . /app/
RUN npm run build
# --> RUN npm run export

RUN ls .next -a
RUN npm install -g pm2

# --> CMD ["pm2-runtime", "ecosystem.config.js", "--env", "production"]
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "server.js"]
```

`ecosystem.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "app",
    script: "./server.js",
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "development",
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    }
  }]
}
```

`next.config.js`:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withSourceMaps = require('@zeit/next-source-maps')()
const webpackConfig = config => {
  console.log = function() {}
  return config
}

module.exports = withCSS(withSourceMaps({
  webpack: webpackConfig,
}))
```

And the errors I got ONLY when running on ther server WITHOUT COMMENTING THE MENTIONED LINES:
`ENV NODE_ENV=production; RUN npm run build`:

```
Error: Could not find a valid build in the '/app/.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
at Server.readBuildId (/app/node_modules/next-server/dist/server/next-server.js:271:23)
at new Server (/app/node_modules/next-server/dist/server/next-server.js:38:29)
at module.exports (/app/node_modules/next-server/index.js:4:10)
at module.exports (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:9:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:8:13)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

`RUN npm run export`:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/.next/BUILD_ID'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.default_1 [as default] (/app/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:36:26)
    at nextExport (/app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-export.js:61:21)
    at commands.(anonymous function).then (/app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:86:36)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/app/.next/BUILD_ID' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! with-redux-wrapper@2.0.0 export: `next export`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the with-redux-wrapper@2.0.0 export script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-09-03T05_11_45_045Z-debug.log
```

Comment: How does your `next.config.js` look? Also it would be interesting to see the contents of your `ecosystem.config.js` file.

Comment: @Cyclonecode I added to the question

Comment: Are you able to run a successful `npm run build` locally, I mean without using docker? And if not what is your error message?

Comment: One problem might be the `withSourceMaps` in your `next.config.js`. Would be nice to see you complete `package.json` file or at least all dependencies.

Comment: One more thing, do you have a `.dockerignore`? I mean if you have built the thing locally so you have a node_modules folder you would otherwise actually copy it into your docker build and over your previously installed `node_modules` folder. The solution would be to add a `.dockerignore` which ignores the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: I created a chat room for this where I might be able to help: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199101/reactjs-next

Comment: And of course you also should ignore the `.next` folder and other temporary build files in your `.dockerignore`.

Comment: Thank you @Cyclonecode Everything is OK with and without docker on my local system.

Comment: @Cyclonecode I have added `.dockerignore` but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about some troubles about `next.js` on `centos` and solved by changing server Operating System to `ubuntu`.

Comment: Missing _next/static... lead to 404

Comment: I got  problem on Ubuntu EC2 too :( any suggestion?